# Unit neo4j-service.service failed to load

Tags: neo4j

installed neo4j 2.2.1 after first removing the previous version.

```
service neo4j-service start
```

produces the error:

***Failed to start neo4j-service.service:  Unit neo4j-service.service failed to load: No such file or directory.***

System is:

system: os => {"name"=>"Ubuntu", "family"=>"Debian", "release"=>{"major"=>"15.04", "full"=>"15.04"}, "lsb"=>{"distcodename"=>"vivid", "distid"=>"Ubuntu", "distdescription"=>"Ubuntu 15.04", "distrelease"=>"15.04", "majdistrelease"=>"15.04"}}

Output of the install script:

```
root@cb-8:~# aptitude install neo4j -y # Install Neo4j, community edition
The following NEW packages will be installed:
daemon{a} neo4j 
0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/53.2 MB of archives. After unpacking 62.4 MB will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package daemon.
(Reading database ... 183856 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../daemon_0.6.4-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking daemon (0.6.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package neo4j.
Preparing to unpack .../archives/neo4j_2.2.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking neo4j (2.2.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (219-7ubuntu3) ...
Setting up daemon (0.6.4-1) ...
Setting up neo4j (2.2.1) ...
update-rc.d: error: initscript does not exist: /etc/init.d/neo4j-service
dpkg: error processing package neo4j (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
  neo4j
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Failed to perform requested operation on package.  Trying to recover:
Setting up neo4j (2.2.1) ...
update-rc.d: error: initscript does not exist: /etc/init.d/neo4j-service
dpkg: error processing package neo4j (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit   status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
  neo4j

root@cb-8:~# service neo4j-service status
● neo4j-service.service
Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

/etc/init.d/neo4j-service does in fact exist.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Mar  5 17:28 /etc/init.d/neo4j-service -> /opt/neo4j-community-2.1.7/bin/neo4j
```

I'm out of ideas and hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

~ Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
2.2.1 was still linking to 2.1.7 somehow.
removed the spurious link and it all worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact error. However, if installing newer version (3.3.0 in my case) of `neo4j` the syntax is different. It should be:

```
service neo4j start
```

not

```
service neo4j-service start
```

To double check you can do:

```
ls /etc/init.d | grep neo4j
```

In my case it finds `neo4j`